# What is justice? Is justice blind?

Tags: consciousness, justice, injustice

Is justice something you find at a courthouse? Where would you find justice?

From my perspective there is no justice until the one being judged has a say in *how* he is being judged. I believe Socrates brought this thought up, what is justice? I know it wasn't sentencing him to banishment or death.

But, by the mercy of God, Socrates is still among us. People throughout history have tried to see how they could judge an individual justly. So they came up with rights, America's founding fathers did it the best way so far (as I believe) because they granted us with certain unalienable rights, that we are endowed with by our creator, to give consent to be governed.

Now I ask this: how would you remove your consent from the ones that govern you? I think this is easy; you must stand and be a man with the utmost respect while pleading your case (thank God for Socrates and Jesus bc of them a good government wouldn't sentence you to death, only jail for questioning there authority).

I hope this comes across well. I can read it and it make sense but it doesn't mean everyone else can, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

It is a very broad topic that one cannot handle without proper introduction to the subject of justice. There are four main distinctions within the concept of justice, there is a distinction between procedural and substantive justice, and between comparative and non-comparative justice.

When you say:

> From my perspective there is no justice until the one being judged has
>   a say in how he is being judged.

That is then a procedural form of justice based on a positive implementation of a certain set of laws. I would refer you to the Stanford Encyclopedia https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/justice/